# elasticsearch mapping of geo_point with null_value

Tags: elasticsearch, null, mapping, geospatial

I ran into an issue related to elasticsearch's **geo_point** while importing from a DB.
My mapping works great if value for **lon** or **lat** field contains real values.

Now it can happen that some rows contain **empty values** for **lon/lat** and if I try to import these I get a **ElasticsearchParseException[latitude must be a number]** error which totaly seems legit.

So I want to set these fields to **0,0 or NULL,NULL** but this is where I get stuck.

I tried to add **'null_value' => '0'** to the mapping but that doesn't seem to work.

This is how the mapping looks like:

```
'_source' => array(
            'enabled' => true
        ),
        'properties' => array(
            'coordinates' => array(
                'type' => 'geo_point',
                'null_value' => '0'
            )
        )
```

Anyone aware of this?

(I am using the PHP Elasticsearch Client.)

Comment: Updated to ES 1.1.1 (see this issue: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/5680) but same problem exists.

Comment: Dealing with null values: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_dealing_with_null_values.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that is fine for me but doesn't solve the actual problem.

In my DB query I convert null to 0 using COALESCE in Posgresql which is similar to IFNULL in mysql.

Comment: This is generally a bad idea, since 0 is an actual value for latitudes and longitudes. Missing values should behave in an explicit manner. If you do this, you should set the `null_value` of the field to be `0`, so it can safely assume that zero is same as missing. Doing so you're at risk of mistakenly treating some coordinates as nulls.

Answer (score 5):

FWIW this is an issue with your document structure, not the presence of null values.

If you have a field `coordinates` with mapping type `geo_point`, you must insert your document with `{..., coordinates: null}` instead of `{..., coordinates: {lat: null, lon: null}}` or similar [equivalent formats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html). The entire field must be missing, not its inner data.